# search and print last occurence of word/string in a line

Tags: grep, line

I have a line in command output and want to search something specific, but not able to do so. I tried lot of ways and searched through forums but could get any suitable answer.

Input String :

INSTANCES       0       x86_64          False   xen     ami-6456a619    i-802cf9ab      m3.medium       aki-fc8f22cc    best-ec2-class        2015-12-09T09:42:22.000Zip-10-10-10-10.in-abc-2.solute.internal       10.10.10.10     ec2-20-19-67-27.in-abc-2.solute.amazonaws.com       20.20.20.20   /dev/sda4       ebs            paravirtual

Output desired :
ec2-20-19-67-27.in-abc-2.solute.amazonaws.com

Tried: grep -o 'ec2[^ ]*.com'
But it gives me output:

ec2-class        2015-12-09T09:42:22.000Zip-10-10-10-10.in-abc-2.solute.internal       10.10.10.10     ec2-20-19-67-27.in-abc-2.solute.amazonaws.com

I can use this also to get desired output, but is it possible to do it with grep only.
grep -o 'ec2[^ ]*.com'|awk '{print $NF}'

Please help. Hope to see answer soon. :)
Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Your regex works for me on my machine in a bash console. Not sure why it's giving you the wrong result. I `echo`ed the input string, piped it to grep with the regex you provide, and got the result you wanted.

Comment: Try escaping the last `.` in your regex so that grep doesn't confuse it with the dot-all operator.

Comment: Thanks for help Akshay. echo is squeezing all the spaces into single space. Hence the output is coming right. As its a command output, so to make things easier i modified it a bit and it worked.
grep ec2|tr -s '\t' ' '|grep -o 'ec2[^ ]*.com'  OR directly
tr -s '\t' ' '|grep -o 'ec2[^ ]*.com' .

But i was looking to do it via grep only, if its possible. However i tried escaping . and tried more regex also but nothing worked.